# Why is the vanadium(3+) ion paramagnetic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions, electronic-configuration, transition-metals

I know that the electron configuration of vanadium is $[\ce{Ar}]\mathrm{4s^2 3d^3}$.

None of the electrons in the 3d subshell are paired. Once it loses these three electrons, shouldn't the remainder of the electrons be paired? How can $\ce{V^{3+}}$ be paramagnetic if it loses all its unpaired electrons?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In addition to the general rules of how electronic configurations of atoms and ions are calculated, the elements from the $\mathrm{d}$-block (a.k.a. the *transition metals*) obey one special rule:

> **In general, electrons are removed from the valence-shell $\mathrm{s}$-orbitals before they are removed from valence $\mathrm{d}$-orbitals when transition metals are ionized.**

<sup>(I took this formulation from [these online lecture notes](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch12/trans.php#ox), but you will find equivalent statements in your textbooks.)</sup>

So, what that does mean is that if you remove electrons from vanadium(0), you will remove the $\mathrm{4s}$ electrons before you remove the $\mathrm{3d}$-electrons. So, you have the following electronic configurations:

> $\ce{V}$ is $\ce{[Ar]} \mathrm{4s^2 3d^3}$
>
> $\ce{V^2+}$ is $\ce{[Ar]} \mathrm{4s^0 3d^3}$
>
> $\ce{V^3+}$ is $\ce{[Ar]} \mathrm{4s^0 3d^2}$
>
> $\ce{V^4+}$ is $\ce{[Ar]} \mathrm{4s^0 3d^1}$
>
> $\ce{V^5+}$ is $\ce{[Ar]} \mathrm{4s^0 3d^0}$

And thus, $\ce{V^3+}$ is paramagnetic, because it has two unpaired $\mathrm{3d}$-electrons. In fact, all the ions above are paramagnetic, except $\ce{V^5+}$.

Comment: is there a reason why you skipped ${V^+ }$ which I suppose is [Ar]3d3 4s1   or [Ar]4s1 3d3 ?