# If you give an electron in a subshell more energy, does it simply "jump" to the next energy level?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, atoms

Suppose you have an electron in the $\ce{2s}$ subshell of an atom. If energy is given to it, does it simply jump to the next energy level (into the $\ce{3s}$ subshell), or does it move into $\ce{2p}$?

Comment: Maybe not duplicate but definitely related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/166687/fundamental-doubts-about-energy-levels-vs-shells-vs-subshells-vs-orbitals

Comment: Transitions must happen with a change in the l quantum number to conserve momentum. the 2s to 3s transition does not happen. The lowest is 2s to 2p actually a doublet. The 2p state can be excited to 3s.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the amount of energy you're supplying.

For example, if you supply light of different wavelengths, the amount of energy each holds is different. Your electron will jump to a subshell corresponding to that energy difference.

Comment: Transitions also happen thermally. There are vibrational and rotational changes with partial excitation, the Raman effect.